# Sharing Laravel Eloquent Models Between Multiple Forked Repositories is possible?

Tags: laravel, git, github, bitbucket, laravel-models

In my Laravel project, I have different types of modules like employee, customer & vendor modules. Recently I split each module into a separate repository. Now if I adding a Model means, I need to duplicate it other repositories also. Is there is any possibility to overcome this?

Is there is any possibility to sync/share the Models folder with other repositories also?

Kindly help me to fix this.

FYI - I'm using Bitbucket for my repositories.

Comment: I would consider why you split them out in the first place if they all have dependencies on each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a [composer package](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages) out of these models so that you can require them in the application. Recently, I found a documentation on laravel packages: https://laravelpackage.com/